# how to switch back to the previous file correctly after using ccompletion in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

how to switch back to the previous file correctly after using ccompletion in notepad++?
I am using ccompletion plugin for notepad++ to find functions and class when I want to know what are they. but when I switch to the new file , I try to switch back using "ctrl+tab", it switch to a file not my previous file when there are many files had been opened 
I remembered that I found that there was a plugin to let notepad++ switch to a place where the cursor I placed last time , but I can not remember what name is the plugin now.maybe that one can solve my problem.
any one tell me how to switch back to my previous file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use a bookmark. Just use Ctrl+F2 in the code line that youre actually, or see this link https://superuser.com/questions/354686/how-possible-use-ctrlf2-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I really understand what you want, but how about:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>